# Android studio project files missing from source control

Tags: android, maven, repository

I am looking a source code repository and it only contains code for an Android project i.e. `src/main/java/com/..` and no project definition files such as `.idea, .iml ,.ipr, .iws` - These files are included in the `.gitignore` file.

There are no files relating to an Android Studio project at all so I cannot open in the IDE. It has been set up for Maven so I can build that way. If I want to run/debug/alter this project what do I do?

Why would somebody exclude all IDE project files?

Comment: Could you be more specific? Which project are you talking about?
Maybe the project in question has been developed using no IDE at all, or using different IDEs for each developer, so the files are in different branches.

Comment: Hmm, well it is an Android project. I do know that it was developed using Android Studio. I'm in the middle of looking through Git for the project files. I think I may have pulled from the wrong place.

Comment: Take a look at the `.gitignore` file.

Comment: Damn, .gitignore contains all the IntelliJ Idea files (.idea, .iml etc..) why? :(

Comment: Delete the elements that you want to push in your repository from `.gitignore` and `git add .` > `git push origin master` again from the original git repository (the one with the IntelliJ files). I guess it solves your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**My Solution**

I am posting solution here as I cannot yet answer my own question.

So, I the solution was in the Maven definition. My codebase was an SDK consisting of numerous libraries and sample apps. Each component had a POM.xml and was all contained using a Parent POM.

All I did was import the Parent POM into Android Studio. Once triggered Android Studio would create its own project files using the POM definitions for each component. All the modules were available in one instance and it built and ran instantly. It was truly beautiful :)

Steps: Import Project -> Select directory containing POM.xml -> "Import project from external model" -> Maven -> Next -> continue to create project.

Comment: Using Android Studio 1.5.1 the Import Project step accept only project with: Manifest + src and additionally a .gradle file.
But as your case, I think, the parent POM doesn't have any manifest, so the import fails. Any solution?

Answer (score 0):

It's easy, the repository/source code owner don't commit the project files because the source code must be independent of the IDE used by people. The projects files of Eclipse are different from one of IntelliJ.

You can clone or download the source code and even not use any IDE. Some poeple prefer working with editors like Emacs or Vi and build the project using the command line.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to create android projects with Android Studio and Eclipse being the main two.

If the author had to maintain project files it would add considerably to the work required as IDEs etc get updates at different rates.

This way the code is "portable" between IDEs and the author can focus on just supporting his work rather than all of the combinations of IDE/Operating Systems.